# How should I add a dash line around UIView which coded with VFL

Tags: swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I just want to draw a dash line around some view coding with VFL. Here is my demo code

```
var ZLDashLineLayerInView = "com.siamLian.ZLDashLineLayerInView"
extension UIView {

    convenience init(frame:CGRect = CGRectZero, lineDashPattern: [NSNumber], strokeColor: UIColor?, fillColor: UIColor? = UIColor.clearColor(), lineWidth: CGFloat = 1, roundingCorners: UIRectCorner = .AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize) {
        let ori_Method =  class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, "drawRect:")

        let my_Method = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, "ZLDrawRect:");
        method_exchangeImplementations(ori_Method, my_Method)

        self.init(frame: frame)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = lineDashPattern
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor?.CGColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor?.CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: frame, byRoundingCorners: roundingCorners, cornerRadii: cornerRadii)
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        //objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ZLDashLineLayerInView, shapeLayer, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        //self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

init view like this :

```
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0), lineDashPattern: [NSNumber(integer: 7), NSNumber(integer: 7)], strokeColor: UIColor.redColor(), lineWidth: 1, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10, 0))
        label.text = "sssssssssssss"
        label.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-100-[label]-100-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["label" : label]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-100-[label]-100-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: ["label" : label]))
```

Because of the label's frame, I init the `shapelayer.path` with wrong frame, so when should i update the shapelayer's path?

Note: 
I know i can custom a view and override the func

```
func drawRect(_ rect: CGRect)
```

I don't want to custom view, any answers appreciated

Comment: You seem to be going to great lengths to avoid subclassing. Why?

Comment: If i want to add a dash line to a button, I have to subclass unbutton ,the same to all other uiview

Comment: Have you tried applying your shape layer properties later in the view controller life cycle like in viewWillAppear? All of your view sizes should be known by that point and you should get the correct frame.